# Listen to mono microphone on all the speakers

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, stereo, mono

I have a mono microphone plugged in the rear pink 3.5mm jack. However, when I check the `Listen to this device` in Microphone's properties (Windows 7 64 bit), I can hear it only in my left speaker.

Is it possible **at the software level** to dupe this mono signal so that i can hear it on **both** speakers, or, even better, on all 5 speakers *(i have a surround 5.1 setup)*?

My sound card is Asus Xonar DG.

Comment: `Microphone's properties`; while I identify your avatar as being Gentoo, it doesn't tell me whether you are really using Gentoo and which desktop environment and tools you would be running. So, as details about your entire software stack are missing; could you enlighten us on what you are really using?

Comment: @Tom Wijsman Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Looked around a little bit on my machine but wasn't able to see anything on my Win7 machine.  Looking through this [post](http://superuser.com/a/355678/179425) it looks like theren't any readily available software options.